# How to gray options in the inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding some things to the Unity asset store and I was wondering, for example, how would I have certain selections grayed out and when the user marks true for something boolean related that the grayed out options will then be interactable. This is all before the user would click Play.

Comment: FYI, do not use the [tag:unity] tag for the game engine. Use [tag:unity3d]. I've fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to make a [Custom Editor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) for the components your create.

As an example, drop this script in your project, and now all lights will have a "lock" to prevent accidental edition on the inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CanEditMultipleObjects, CustomEditor(typeof(Light))]
public class LightEditor : Editor {

    bool editAllowed = false;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI () {

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        editAllowed = EditorGUILayout.ToggleLeft(" I know what I'm doing", editAllowed);
        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        GUI.enabled = editAllowed;
        DrawDefaultInspector();
    }
}
```

Like all `Editor` scripts, [it should be within a folder called "Editor"](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html), so that Unity doesn't compile it into the final build. [More info on that](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder#.22Editor.22)